# load PHP extension module failed

Tags: php, c, linux, php-extension, undefined-function

What I would like is to build a *.so , then make it as a PHP extenstion module and call the functions in the *.so  via PHP.

My step is as below:

1. Build the C library under linux, first Create the hello.c

   ```
   int hello_add(int a, int b)
   {
       return a+b;
   }
   ```

Then build as below:

```
    gcc -O -c -fPIC -o hello.o hello.c
    gcc -shared -o libhello.so hello.o
```

2. download the php 5.2.17 source code
3. tar -zxvf php.5.2.17.tar.gz
4. cd php.5.2.17
5. ./configure ./configure --prefix=/home/user1/php-5.2.17
6. make & make install
7. cd ext;
8. ./ext_skel --extname=hello
9. cd hello
10. edit config.m4  by removing the dnl in line 16-18 then save and quit.

    `16:  PHP_ARG_ENABLE(hello, whether to enable hello support,
    17:  dnl Make sure that the comment is aligned:
    18:  [  --enable-hello           Enable hello support])`
11. execute the command:    /home/user1/php-5.2.17/bin/phpize
12. open php_hello.h, add 
    `PHP_FUNCTION(hello_add);`
13. open hello.c change to:

    `zend_function_entry hello_functions[] = {
    PHP_FE(confirm_hello_compiled,  NULL)       /* For testing, remove later. */
    PHP_FE(hello_add,   NULL)       /* For testing, remove later. */
    {NULL, NULL, NULL}  /* Must be the last line in hello_functions[] */
    };`

    At the end of the file, add

    `PHP_FUNCTION(hello_add)
    {
        long int a, b;
        long int result;
        if (zend_parse_parameters(ZEND_NUM_ARGS() TSRMLS_CC, "ll", &a, &b) == FAILURE) {
            return;
        }
        result = hello_add(a, b);
        RETURN_LONG(result);
    }`
14. `./configure --with-php-config=/home/usr1/php-5.2.17/bin/php-config`
15. `make LDFLAGS=-lhello`
16. Then the hello.so is generated under /home/usre/php-5.2.17/ext/hello/modules, but 
     use `nm hello.so` it prints:

    ```
                `U hello_add
                 0000000000000a98 T _init`
    ```
17. Create a php file to test:

    `<?php
    if(!dl('btest.so'))
    {
        echo "can not load hello.so";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "load is done";
        echo hello_add(3,4);// here it will throw error in the log
    }
    ?>`

in the log, it complains: 
[28-Sep-2014 18:38:28] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function hello_add() ....

BTW, I copied the hello.so into another LAMP environment, not using the PHP just build. Both of the version is 5.2.17.

can anybody point what's going on?

Comment: You should do `./configure ... --enable-hello`; also, if you're wrapping a library you should use the `--with-hello=DIR` syntax.

Comment: which step do you mean? step 5 or step 14 ?

Comment: At step 14, to configure your extension.

Comment: @Jack, I tried both by adding --enable-hello and --with-hello. Neither of them doesn't work.

Comment: When you change the `.m4` you must rerun `phpize`.

Comment: @Jack, I did it as what said. Still not working.

Answer (score 1):

While in step 15, change LDFLAGS=lhello to  LDFLAGS=hello.o , then it works.  I don't know what's wrong with the *.so.  Anyway it's fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

I tried --with-hello=DIR, what's the DIR?  is the path of libhello.so or the php extension--hello 's path?